# Tailwind Vendor Prefixes

Tags: tailwind-css, vendor-prefix

Is there a way to use vendor prefixes in tailwind css?

```css
.search::-webkit-search-cancel-button{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Autoprefixer as recommended in the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#vendor-prefixes

Answer (score 2):

To apply styles to vendor-specific pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements in Tailwind, arbitrary variants can be used.

For example, to hide the [`::-webkit-search-cancel-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button) on a specific `<input>` element:

```html
<input class="[&::-webkit-search-cancel-button]:hidden" type="search" />
```

Comment: [Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eRquH3QdWa)